# Is there an example of an infinite signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals

In the real world, Is there an example of an infinite signal?

Comment: You mean a signal that extends from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in time? Hmmm, think about it for a moment.

Comment: Imagine you could show a signal has existed from $t=-\infty$ (or from $t=0$ if you prefer)... How could you prove it will exist until $t=\infty$?

Comment: @MattL. No, a signal that extends from 0 to $\infty$ . but, I don't no. :(

Comment: We can arbitrarily invent signals. For example, $s(t)=\sin(t)$ is infinitely long. Is that a real-world signal? I don't know – but if we say "the signal is the electric field strength of a plane electromagnetic wavefront over time, shot from earth into the vastness of space", that's a pretty real signal, and it's pretty infinite...

Comment: @MBaz In physics, the energy is always  existed. is not possible boute the signal ?

Comment: @niloofarjamshidi no, that's not true. Physicists don't generally say energy has always existed. That might or might not have been the case before the big bang. (if that big bang existed in the way we model it did) The point really is that we literally can't say anything changed in whatever was before the big bang. If nothing is there, nothing can change. If nothing can change, then there's no signal. But this is purely of philosophical value here.

Comment: The question really is, what do you need that example for?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's a question that haunts my mind.

Comment: well, don't know if this helps you, but: A signal is really just *anything quantifiable* changing along *any one or more axis*. So, voltage over time can be a signal, but also position over time or gravitational pull over distance. So, if you imagine you draw a plot "gravitational pull over distance from center of all mass in the universe", that signal will be infinitely long (the universe never ends). But, to give another example, as said, the (mathematical) signal $\sin (x)$ is perfectly sensible and infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the proposed [heat death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe), no active life form will be available to measure the rest of any given signal. That's not a *real world* to anyone.

One could define a signal not as function of time but as function of location, and wrap around the location. An example is the present ambient temperature as function of distance traveled to the east from Pontianak, Indonesia, on the Equator. We don't know if the universe is infinitely large so measurements on a straight line would be a bit iffy.

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: This would be a cyclo-infinite signal, if such a term exists. Good answer!